# How can I print to stdout from within a trap called during eval

Tags: bash, eval, stdout, bash-trap

I expected the following script to print `This is redirected to 'output'.` when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap_function(){
    trap '' EXIT INT TERM
    echo "This is redirected to 'output'."
    touch this_will_exist
}
trap trap_function EXIT INT TERM

eval "sleep 100" &> output
```

Instead, nothing is displayed, and the text goes to the file `output`. How can I escape the redirect from within `trap_function` and have the text displayed to the user?

`echo "This is redirected to 'output'." > /dev/stdout` does not have the desired effect.

I run GNU bash, version 4.3.48 in Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

Comment: It works correctly in the online bash and e.g. zsh but does not print when running locally in Ubuntu or WLS.

Comment: Och, you are right, sorry. Looks like eval does not inherit traps. You can replicate it online (or another issue) by adding kill signal before the sleep exists, like `( sleep 0.5; kill -s SIGINT $$; ) &`.

Comment: The trap is executed. The file `this_will_exist` is created and the text will end up in the file `output`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Your are right: http://tpcg.io/IF6Dtp

Comment: It *is* writing to standard output; the question is, where is it inheriting standard output *from*?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to have `eval` run in a subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap_function(){
    trap '' EXIT INT TERM
    echo "This is redirected to 'output'."
    touch this_will_exist
}
trap trap_function EXIT INT TERM

(eval "sleep 100") &> output
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's happening one must know, that in order for bash to print anything that is send to stdout (which is the file descriptor 1) it sets the file descriptor 1 to the current terminal. This is nicely explained here https://catonmat.net/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three.

`&> output` replaces the terminal in file descriptor 1 and 2 with the file `output`. So there is no file descriptor left, to which `echo "..."` could send that would be displayed in the terminal. Hence, we have two possible solutions:

## Redirecting to the current terminal

This works with the utility `tty` that returns the current user terminal.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

trap_function(){
    trap '' EXIT INT TERM
    echo "This is redirected to 'output'." &>$(tty)
    touch this_will_exist
}
trap trap_function EXIT INT TERM

eval "sleep 100" &> output
```

However, it may not be possible to capture this output with a wrapper.

## Redirecting over another file descriptor

This solution requires that an additional file descriptor is set to the current terminal (e.g., 123). We can simply use what is already set in the file descriptor 1 before we replace it with `output` by `123>&1`. Then we can set the file descriptor of `echo` (which is stdout) to what we stored in file descriptor 123:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

trap_function(){
    trap '' EXIT INT TERM
    echo "This is redirected to 'output'." >&123
    touch this_will_exist
}
trap trap_function EXIT INT TERM

eval "sleep 100" 123>&1 &> output
```